# Extending a static PNG

Tags: premiere

is there a way in Premier Pro 2019 with a keyboard shortcut to extend a static png to the end of a clip?  For instance, I've edited the program and its ready.  I then insert the program or network logo (think the CBS EYE as an example) onto the its own video layer.  I want that watermark now to stay up for the entire program.  I've been doing it manually for quite a while, just dragging the end point to the end of the program, but that is quite tedious.  Anyone know of a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the end of the png clip, so that the edit is highlighted. Then move your playhead to the end of the program, and hit <kbd>e</kbd>, which is the shortcut for extend edit. More info can be found by [reading the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/trimming-clips1.html#Trimwithkeyboardshortcuts).